# How to draw custom flowchart diagram with tikz?

Tags: tikz-styles, flow-charts, workflow

I want to draw a flowchart diagram like :
[image]
This diagram is generated by Geogebra. Here are codes:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49,0.49,1}
\definecolor{yqqqqq}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{qqffqq}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\fill[line width=0.4pt,color=qqffqq,fill=qqffqq,fill opacity=0.34] (4,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,4) -- (4,4) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=0.4pt,color=yqqqqq,fill=yqqqqq,fill opacity=0.38] (-1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (-1,0) -- cycle;
\fill[color=yqqqqq,fill=yqqqqq,fill opacity=0.38] (1,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,0) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\fill[color=yqqqqq,fill=yqqqqq,fill opacity=0.38] (4,1) -- (5,1) -- (5,0) -- (4,0) -- cycle;
\fill[color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,fill opacity=0.49] (-1,-3) -- (0,-3) -- (0,-4) -- (-1,-4) -- cycle;
\fill[color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,fill opacity=0.49] (1,-3) -- (2,-3) -- (2,-4) -- (1,-4) -- cycle;
\fill[color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,fill opacity=0.49] (4,-3) -- (5,-3) -- (5,-4) -- (4,-4) -- cycle;
\fill[color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,fill opacity=0.49] (6,-3) -- (7,-3) -- (7,-4) -- (6,-4) -- cycle;
\fill[color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,fill opacity=0.49] (9,-3) -- (10,-3) -- (10,-4) -- (9,-4) -- cycle;
\fill[color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,fill opacity=0.49] (12,-3) -- (13,-3) -- (13,-4) -- (12,-4) -- cycle;
\fill[color=yqqqqq,fill=yqqqqq,fill opacity=0.38] (9,1) -- (10,1) -- (10,0) -- (9,0) -- cycle;
\fill[color=yqqqqq,fill=yqqqqq,fill opacity=0.38] (6,1) -- (7,1) -- (7,0) -- (6,0) -- cycle;
\fill[color=qqffqq,fill=qqffqq,fill opacity=0.47] (13,4) -- (13,3.6) -- (13.4,3.6) -- (13.4,4) -- cycle;
\fill[color=yqqqqq,fill=yqqqqq,fill opacity=0.34] (13.05,3.38) -- (13.05,2.98) -- (13.45,2.98) -- (13.45,3.38) -- cycle;
\fill[color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,fill opacity=0.39] (13.05,2.7) -- (13.05,2.31) -- (13.45,2.31) -- (13.45,2.71) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=0.4pt,color=qqffqq] (4,5)-- (5,5);
\draw [line width=0.4pt,color=qqffqq] (5,5)-- (5,4);
\draw [line width=0.4pt,color=qqffqq] (5,4)-- (4,4);
\draw [line width=0.4pt,color=qqffqq] (4,4)-- (4,5);
\draw [line width=0.4pt,color=yqqqqq] (-1,1)-- (0,1);
\draw [line width=0.4pt,color=yqqqqq] (0,1)-- (0,0);
\draw [line width=0.4pt,color=yqqqqq] (0,0)-- (-1,0);
\draw [line width=0.4pt,color=yqqqqq] (-1,0)-- (-1,1);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (1,1)-- (2,1);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (2,1)-- (2,0);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (2,0)-- (1,0);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (1,0)-- (1,1);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (4,1)-- (5,1);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (5,1)-- (5,0);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (5,0)-- (4,0);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (4,0)-- (4,1);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (-1,-3)-- (0,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (0,-3)-- (0,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (0,-4)-- (-1,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (-1,-4)-- (-1,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (1,-3)-- (2,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (2,-3)-- (2,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (2,-4)-- (1,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (1,-4)-- (1,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (4,-3)-- (5,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (5,-3)-- (5,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (5,-4)-- (4,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (4,-4)-- (4,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (6,-3)-- (7,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (7,-3)-- (7,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (7,-4)-- (6,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (6,-4)-- (6,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (9,-3)-- (10,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (10,-3)-- (10,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (10,-4)-- (9,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (9,-4)-- (9,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (12,-3)-- (13,-3);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (13,-3)-- (13,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (13,-4)-- (12,-4);
\draw [color=qqqqff] (12,-4)-- (12,-3);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (9,1)-- (10,1);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (10,1)-- (10,0);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (10,0)-- (9,0);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (9,0)-- (9,1);
\draw(4.47,2.57) circle (0.43cm);
\draw(8.01,-1.42) circle (0.42cm);
\draw [->] (4.5,4) -- (4.49,2.99);
\draw [->] (-0.52,1.65) -- (-0.5,1);
\draw [->] (-0.5,0) -- (-0.47,-3);
\draw [->] (1.55,-0.06) -- (1.55,-3);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (6,1)-- (7,1);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (7,1)-- (7,0);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (7,0)-- (6,0);
\draw [color=yqqqqq] (6,0)-- (6,1);
\draw (-0.52,1.65)-- (9.53,1.67);
\draw [->] (1.5,1.66) -- (1.5,1);
\draw [->] (6.47,1.66) -- (6.51,0.94);
\draw [->] (9.53,1.67) -- (9.51,1);
\draw [->] (4.49,2.14) -- (4.49,1);
\draw [->] (4.56,0) -- (4.59,-2.94);
\draw [->] (9.58,-0.06) -- (8.04,-1);
\draw [->] (6.49,0) -- (8.04,-1);
\draw (6.51,-2.29)-- (12.6,-2.29);
\draw [->] (6.51,-2.29) -- (6.54,-3);
\draw [->] (9.56,-2.29) -- (9.56,-3.06);
\draw [->] (12.6,-2.29) -- (12.6,-3);
\draw [->] (8,-1.84) -- (8.01,-2.29);
\draw [dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (2.61,0.51)-- (3.45,0.53);
\draw [dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (7.68,0.51)-- (8.58,0.51);
\draw [dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (2.61,-3.48)-- (3.45,-3.46);
\draw [dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (7.66,-3.53)-- (8.53,-3.49);
\draw [dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (10.65,-3.49)-- (11.58,-3.48);



\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=qqqqff] (4.5,4.55) node {$B$};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (9.81,0.62) node {A};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (-0.38,0.58) node {A};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (1.5,0.56) node {A};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (4.6,0.56) node {A};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (6.58,0.56) node {A};

\draw[color=qqqqff] (-0.4,-3.51) node {D};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (1.57,-3.53) node {D};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (4.64,-3.51) node {D};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (6.5,-3.53) node {D};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (9.4,-3.51) node {D};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (12.5,-3.49) node {D};


\draw[color=qqqqff] (4.47,2.64) node {E};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (8.01,-1.39) node {G};

\draw[color=uququq] (13.9,3.81) node {color1};
\draw[color=uququq] (13.97,3.22) node {color2};
\draw[color=uququq] (13.97,2.55) node {color3};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this diagram does not look as good. So I have tried to do better diagram with the following code but failed to produce a complete diagram. Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}%{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning,shadows,trees}
\tikzstyle{rectangle1} = [rectangle,  minimum width=0.4cm, minimum height=0.4cm, text centered, draw=black, drop shadow, fill=green!20,  %rounded corners, font=\sffamily
]

\tikzstyle{rectangle2} = [rectangle,  minimum width=0.4cm, minimum height=0.4cm, text centered, draw=black, drop shadow, fill=red!10,  %rounded corners, font=\sffamily
]

\tikzstyle{rectangle3} = [rectangle,  minimum width=0.4cm, minimum height=0.4cm, text centered, draw=black, drop shadow, fill=green!30,  %rounded corners, font=\sffamily
]

%\tikzstyle{startstop} = [ellipse, drop shadow, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black,drop shadow, fill=green!30,  %font=\sffamily]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, drop shadow,fill=blue!1]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text width=3cm, text centered,drop shadow, draw=black, fill=orange!1]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=green!1, 
text width=4.5em, text badly centered, drop shadow, node distance=3cm, aspect=1.7,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
%opening

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%


\newcommand\ColorBox[2][0.4em]{%
    \frame{\textcolor{#2}{\rule{#1}{#1}}}%
} % for legend



\title{Creating Flowcharts with TikZ}
\author{MD Kutubuddin Sardar}


\begin{document}
%   \maketitle
%   \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

%============Start node===============
\node (start) [rectangle1] {$S$};
\node (T1) [rectangle2,text width=0.4cm, below of=start] { $T_1$};
\node (T2) [rectangle2,text width=0.4cm, right of=T1] {$T_2$};
%-----------End node-------------

%============Start connecting path===============
\draw [arrow] (start.south)  -- +(0.0,-0.5)-| node[xshift=1cm, yshift=1cm, above, midway] {} (T2);

%-----------End connecting path-------------

%============Start legend part===============
\node[anchor=south,scale=0.4] 
at ([xshift=4cm,yshift=3cm]current bounding box.south west)
{
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
    \begin{tabular}{|cp{1cm}|}
    \hline
    \ColorBox{yellow!10!white} &  \tiny Some \\
    \ColorBox{red!10} & \tiny color \\
    \ColorBox{red!20} & \tiny description \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
};
%-----------End legend part-------------



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I do the complete diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution using `matrix of nodes`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49,0.49,1}
\definecolor{yqqqqq}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{qqffqq}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    square node/.style={
      minimum width = 1cm,
      minimum height = 1cm,
    },
    circ/.style={
      minimum width = 1cm,
      minimum height = 1cm,
      draw = black,
      thick,
      circle
    },
    b/.style={
      square node,
      fill = qqffqq,
      opacity = 0.3,
      label = center:\textcolor{blue}{$B$},
    },
    a/.style={
      square node,
      fill = yqqqqq,
      opacity = 0.4,
      label = center:\textcolor{blue}{$A$},
    },
    d/.style={
      square node,
      fill = qqqqff,
      opacity = 0.4,
      label = center:\textcolor{blue}{$D$},
    },
    ellipsis/.style={
      square node,
      label = center:\textcolor{blue}{$\cdots$},
    },
    line/.style={
      draw,
      -latex
    }
  ]

  % nodes
  \matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, column sep = 0.7cm, row sep = 1cm] {
  & & & \node (B) [b]{}; & & & & & \\
  & & & \node (E)[circ, label = center:\textcolor{blue}{$E$}]{}; & & & & & \\
  \node (A1) [a]{}; & \node (A2) [a]{}; & \node[ellipsis]{}; & \node (A3) [a]{}; & \node (A4) [a]{}; & \node[ellipsis]{}; & \node (A5) [a]{}; & & \\
  & & & & & \node (G) [circ, label = center:\textcolor{blue}{$G$}]{}; & & & \\
  \node (D1) [d]{}; & \node (D2) [d]{}; & \node[ellipsis]{}; & \node (D3) [d]{}; & \node (D4) [d]{}; & \node (El) [ellipsis]{}; & \node (D5) [d]{}; & \node[ellipsis]{}; & \node (D6) [d]{}; \\
  };

  % arrows
  \draw[line] (B) -- (E);
  \coordinate (EA) at ($(E)!0.5!(A3)$);
  \draw[line] (E) -- (A3);
  \foreach \x in {A1,A2,A4,A5} \draw[line] (EA) -| (\x);
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3} \draw[line] (A\x) -- (D\x);
  \draw[line] (A4) -- (G);
  \draw[line] (A5) -- (G);
  \coordinate (GD) at ($(G)!0.5!(El)$);
  \draw[line] (G) -- (GD);
  \foreach \x in {D4,D5,D6} \draw[line] (GD) -| (\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]